# Issues with finding out the active count of threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I need some help in trying to understand what is happening with the below code. Basically i am trying to understand how the statement threading.active_count() works in Python:

```
import threading
import time

def worker(count):
    for c in range(count,-1,-1):
        threadname = threading.currentThread().getName()
        time.sleep(2)
        print ("Value of count {} from thread {}".format(c,threadname))
        threadcount = threading.active_count()
        print ("Threadcount is :",threadcount)

mainthreadname = threading.currentThread().getName()
print ("Starting new thread from main thread:",mainthreadname)
t1 = threading.Thread(target=worker,args=(10,))
t1.start()
time.sleep(5)
print ("main thread exiting!")
```

The issue here is that the even though the line to get the active thread count is nested inside the range block that line keeps on executing with an active thread count of 1(which i think is the main thread) even after the range block finishes execution.

Basically if anyone runs it in their machine they would get what i am trying to point at.

can someone please point out what is the issue here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think that line keeps executing after the "range block" finishes execution? (Also, there's no such thing as a "range block".)

Answer (score 0):

The Threadcount is always 3 for me.  Also, consider changing time.sleep(5) to t1.join(), which will return when the worker finishes executing.